# ICU Transliteration Katakana filter not applying to Halfwidth Katakana Voiced Sound Mark

Tags: java, unicode, icu

I am trying to do a very specific transform on some text, using the ICU Transliterator as described [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

My text contains both halfwidth katakana characters and regular latin characters. I want to convert the halfwidth katakana to fullwidth katakana, while leaving non-katakana characters unchanged.

I wanted to simply apply the standard "Halfwidth-Fullwidth" ICU transform together with a filter that selects only Katakana, and this did not work - the Katakana filter did not apply to the [Halfwidth Katakana Voiced Sound Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff9e/index.htm), which surprised me. I'm trying to figure out if this is intended or a bug.

See the code below for examples. I tried:

1. Halfwidth-Fullwidth without a filter - affected too much
2. Halfwidth-Fullwidth with Katakana filter - didn't affect U+ff9e - is this a bug?
3. Halfwidth-Fullwidth with negative Latin filter - still affected spaces.
4. Halfwidth-Fullwidth with compound negative filter - too fragile.

Any ideas?
Is there somewhere I can check what characters are actually included in the ICU `[:Katakana:]` filter?

```java
void transliterateWithRules(String original, String rules) {
    Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.createFromRules("mytest", rules, Transliterator.FORWARD);
    String result = transliterator.transliterate(original);
    System.out.println(String.format("Transliteration result: \"%s\", codepoints: %s", result, toCodepoints(result)));
}

void test() {
    String input = "ｷﾞ a"; // Unicode Codepoints: \uff77 \uff9e \u20 \u61

    transliterateWithRules(input, ":: Halfwidth-Fullwidth;");
    // Result:
    // "ギ　ａ", codepoints: \u30ae \u3000 \uff41
    // This makes everything fullwidth, including the space and the latin 'a'

    transliterateWithRules(input, "::  [:Katakana:]; :: Halfwidth-Fullwidth;");
    // Result:
    // "キﾞ a", codepoints: \u30ad \uff9e \u20 \u61
    // This makes the Katakana KI fullwidth, and skips the space and 'a' as intended, but it also
    // skips the Halfwidth Katakana Voiced Sound Mark (U+FF9E), which I expected to be converted.

    transliterateWithRules(input, ":: [:^Latin:] Halfwidth-Fullwidth;");
    // Result:
    // "ギ　a", codepoints: \u30ae \u3000 \u61
    // Skips the latin 'a' as intended, but makes the space Fullwidth, which I don't want

    transliterateWithRules(input, ":: [[:^Latin:]&[^\\ ]]; :: Halfwidth-Fullwidth;");
    // Result:
    // "ギ a", codepoints: \u30ae \u20 \u61
    // Exactly what I want, for this example - but relying on a list of exclusions is fragile, since I am only
    // excluding what I currently know about.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a list of characters in the `[:Katakana:]` set [here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AKatakana%3A%5D&g=&i=), which contains neither `U+FF9E` nor `U+FF9F`.

This is because `[:Katakana:]` is equivalent to `[:Script=Katakana:]`, which tests the ["Script" property](http://unicode.org/reports/tr24/) of a character. Both `U+FF9E` and `U+FF9F` are flagged as being used in Hiragana *and* Katakana text, so their script property is "Common" (rather than something like `ｷ`, which is exclusively "Katakana"). There is a "Script Extensions" property which contains both scripts, but this isn't checked by `[:Katakana:]`.

You can either manually add them to the set (`[[:Katakana:]\uFF9E\uFF9F]`), or create a set that includes script extensions:

```
[\p{sc=Katakana}\p{scx=Katakana}]
```

(Note that this contains a few other shared characters, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Unicode set. I ended up creating a filter that is the union of the Katakana set and the common halfwidth characters I'm interested in, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

By browsing through the ICU code (CjkBreakEngine.java:26) I noticed the following pattern being used:

```
fKatakanaWordSet.applyPattern("[[:Katakana:]\\uff9e\\uff9f]");
```

Based on this it might be intentional not to include these sound marks, altought I cannot tell why.